# How can I create web fragment project in Intellij Idea

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, servlet-3.0

I'm looking for creating a small web framework on top of the standard servlet-3.x specifications. Main motive is to reduce the boiler plate codes and abstractions. After I read the servlet specifications it looks without using JAX-RS or SparkJava I can create small web framework for API developments.

I'm planning to use the web-fragments method to create my framework level filters, and other beans and package it as `jar`. So application developer create the `war` project with `web.xml` with the `metadata-complete` option set to `false`.

I can see the web-fragment project template in `eclipse` but I want to develop this project using maven. With Intellij I can't see any such options for web fragment projects alone. I want to create simple maven project which ship the jar with `web-fragment.xml` in it, so other war projects can make use of it.

So is there any plugins or other options available to develop web fragment projects in Intellij ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any jar file added to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of a web application is technically a "web fragment", whether it has a `META-INF/web-fragment.xml` file or not.

Therefore, you just need to create a maven project with "jar" packaging and import it into Intellij Idea.

Comment: I Got it worked using gradle instead of maven. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a maven project for the fragment. Set the `packaging` to `jar`. There is no need to create a `war` project.
2. Configure an empty Artifact in the Project Structure dialog:
   [image]
3. Using the toolbar buttons, add the `WEB-INF/lib` folders. Then create an Archive and add the compile output:
   [image]
4. Add a Tomcat run configuration, and in the *Deployment* tab, add the Artifact you just created:
   [image]

---

I created an example project that includes all that: https://github.com/ThomasR/web-fragment-idea. Please note that it requires [TomEE+](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomee/tomee-7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plus.zip).